# Filter a listview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, filter

Currently I have a program that is able to write to a `ListView` with column named : `number`, `time`, description . This listview is not bound to anything data, I'm just basically writing into it using the code.

What I want to do is to have a `TextBox`, whereby if the user wants to look at particular number i.e. 2, when they type into the textbox, then I want the listview to only show data with number = 2. When there's nothing in the textbox, I want the listview to show all the data.

I have being looking around on the internet and I didn't seem to find a filter method. Does it even exist and if so how would I go about implementing this.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you use a `DataGridView` instead?

Comment: The listview doesnt do filtering.  Neither does the DGV unless you use a datasource

Comment: is there any other option that I have available. A different approach maybe. All I want for the user to be able to easily see all the data together. Please anyone. Thank you in advance

Comment: `A different approach maybe` a DGv with a datasource that you manage **is** a different approach, no?

Comment: While I recommend using a `DataGridView` with `DataSource` as mentioned by me and @Plutonix, but I posted a solution that you can use in cases that you need to use `ListView`,

Comment: If you are also interested in `DataGridView` approach, you can search in the site or  ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I recommend using a `DataGridView` with `DataSource` but in cases that you need to use `ListView`, you can use this solution.

You can filter your list view this way:

- Define a member field as backup storage of items:
- In form `Load` after adding items to list view, store each item in that member field
- Put a `TextBox` and a `Button` on form and handle `Click` event of the `Button` and in the handler, first clear all items of `ListView` then each item from that backup storage that matches with criteria.

Member Field for Backup of Items

```
Private ItemsBackup As New List(Of ListViewItem)
```

Fill backup after loading items in `ListView` in the form `Load` event

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
    ItemsBackup.Add(item)
Next
```

Code of Filter

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.ListView1.BeginUpdate()

    Me.ListView1.Items.Clear()
    For Each item As ListViewItem In ItemsBackup
        If (item.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.TextBox1.Text)) Then
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        End If
    Next

    Me.ListView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

You can also use above code for `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox`.

Here is a test data:

```
For i = 1 To 30
    Dim item As New ListViewItem(i.ToString())
    item.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Now.AddHours(i))
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: I tried your method, however when you mentioned about adding the backup to the form load, this is not possible since item are added to the listview as the system collects new data.  What I can store is a imagelist, which contains all the images to be added into the listview later on. Is it possible to add the imagelist to the itemBackup, if possible what do I change in the for loop you provided. Doing it this way I will show either all information, or the ones that corresponds to the image. Thank You

Comment: Please see the original edited post for information on how I implemented your code and the way I write to the listview. Please can you identify the problem. Thank you

Comment: Dear @Satvir, You should test the solution in a clean states. For example, fill a list view in form load, then apply my solution and see the result.

Comment: The way you fill backup in `Button1_Click` cause the second time you clicked the button, the back will destroy and you will store filtered items in backup.

Comment: Another important thing, you are adding the item with empty text so obviously you will have problem in search.

Comment: I added a test data that you can test the solution using these data. Also remove those backup code from `Button1_Click` which destroy backup after second click.

Comment: Also if your data is not loading in form load and you are adding data continuously to the list view, please don't edit the question anymore and revert it back to your original question and accept this answer and ask a new question.  And please revert your question back to its original state :)

Comment: I see the problem. Thanks. Last point Your code is only looking at the first column is there a way to tell it to look at the second column and search in the second column to find all the relevant data.

Comment: You can use `item.SubItems(index of sub item).Text` in search.

Answer (score 0):

A normal .NET `ListView` can't do this without a considerable amount of work. So, you could use `ObjectListView` -- an open source wrapper around a standard .NET ListView -- which has already done all the work for you.

It has [built-in filtering](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#is-there-an-easy-way-to-only-show-rows-that-contain-some-text) (and highlighting)

[image]