# How to execute advance Listview Search

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, search

Using Windows forms, My 'listview' have multiple columns as shown in the picture.

[image]

I have been trying to make this txtbox_search to be advanced. When any character, word or number is inserted, i want Some columns of my listview to be traversed to look for the character, word, number and bring up data related to the input.

---

Like when i enter: txtbox_search.Text = "a"

It should travers column "Name" and fill Listview with data:

entire row that has a name which starts with "a" such as "Anwar"

entire row that has a name which starts with "a" such as "Anas"

so on with entire rows that has a name which starts with "A..."

---

when i enter: txtbox_search.Text = "1"

It should travers column "ID" and fill Listview with data:

entire row that has a ID which starts with "1" such as "1002"

entire row that has a ID which starts with "1" such as "1112"

so on with entire rows that has a ID which starts with "1..."

---

so far i have been trying this for 2 days and end up with this much:

```
private void textBox_DEC_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListViewItem Items in listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items)
    {
        if(Items.Text == textBox_DEC_Search.Text)
        {
            listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.Clear();
            listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.Add(Items);
        }
    }
    if(textBox_DEC_Search.Text == "" || textBox_DEC_Search.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        CusList Cus = new CusList();
        Cus.CustomersList(listView_DEC_CustomerList);
    }
}
```

This code only travers first column and bring up data that matches the inserted ID, only if the Complete ID matches with txtbox_search.Text how can i make this possible? (i want it to be on client side, not from sql/database). Guides and sample code helps will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you have basically 2 criteria: if it is a letter search in Name, if it is a number search in ID did I get it right?

Comment: I recommend using a data-bound `DataGridView` and perform filtering using the `List<T>` or the `DataTable` which is `DataSource` of `DataGridView`.  Anyway if you want to continue using ListView, take a look at [Find ListView Items based on text of items and sub items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37075549/3110834) and [Filter a ListView in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34226854/3110834)

Comment: yes, you got it right, @MongZhu

Comment: reading the link you provided, @RezaAghaei. Thank you for the concern ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish between your 2 criteria you could use the following:

```
if (textBox_DEC_Search.Text.All(x => Char.IsNumber(x)))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Number");
    // search through ID
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name");
    // search through Name
}
```

It basically checks whether your input is solely numeric.

EDIT:

To check for similarity you cold use [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx) of [String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) to make the search a little more flexible

to look for the ID or NAME you need to access the subitems!

since ID is your first column check `SubItems[0]`

```
if(Items.SubItems[0].Text.StartsWith(textBox_DEC_Search.Text) || 
   Items.SubItems[0]Text.Contains(textBox_DEC_Search.Text))
```

since NAME is your second column check `SubItems[1]`

```
if(Items.SubItems[1].Text.StartsWith(textBox_DEC_Search.Text) || 
   Items.SubItems[1]Text.Contains(textBox_DEC_Search.Text))
```

One Problem is this line:

```
listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.Clear();
```

because it will erase the first found result when the second is found.
So if you find 10 matches the previous 9 will be deleted!
I suggest to make first the entire search and then add the results if there are any:

```
private void textBox_DEC_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // index is 0 if numeric for ID or 1 if not for NAME
    int ind = textBox_DEC_Search.Text.All(x => Char.IsNumber(x)) ? 0 : 1;


    List<ListViewItem> matchlist = new List<ListViewItem>();

    foreach(ListViewItem Items in listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items)
    {
        if(Items.SubItems[ind].Text.StartsWith(textBox_DEC_Search.Text) || 
          Items.SubItems[ind]Text.Contains(textBox_DEC_Search.Text))            
        {
            matchlist.Add(Items);
        }
    }

    // if you have found something add the all results
    if(matchlist.Any())            
    {
        listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.Clear();
        listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.AddRange(matchlist.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: Although this solution should work I would vote to follow the advice of @RezaAghaei. It is less messy and confusing than directly manipulating the `ListView`

Comment: i tried the more flexible part of code that you shared. It does bring up data, but not all the items that contains that 'inserted string value'
it brings up just 1 row and it is still only traversing "ID" column of listview.

Comment: @ARr0w the problem is `listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.Clear();` if you find one you delete the rest, so if you find the second result you delete the first

Comment: @ARr0w I made a new edit and considered the clearing of the search results. Please check it out and comment

Comment: Error at this line: 
        `listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.AddRange(matchlist);`

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]

Comment: Thanks @MongZhu, i figured out. I tried all of its properties and one worked. which was `matchlist.ToArray();`

Comment: @ARr0w that means that you need an array: so the solution here would be : `listView_DEC_CustomerList.Items.AddRange(matchlist.ToArray());`

Comment: Yeah @MongZhu i figured out. I was playing with the properties. Thanks Alot! 
Very much appreciated ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using == which looks for an exact match try one of the following (I am assuming 'Text' is the column name in the list containing the name - if not change it to Items.Name (for example)

1. if you want to search on 'starting with' then try

   ```
   if (Items.Text.StartsWith(textBox_DEC_Search.Text.Trim())
   ```
2. if you want to search based on the fact that a part of the string should be looked up then try

   ```
   if (Items.Text.Contains(textBox_DEC_Search.Text.Trim())
   ```
3. You can similarly do for any other column you would like to search on. if you want to make the search case insensitive then use .ToLower() on the string and the column name.

Comment: still trans-versing only first column of listview and if found it returns 'one' random row. Not all related to inserted string.

Comment: you're answer turned out to be useful for me. Thanks for sharing the search case insensitive knowledge with me :) @anil